# javascript- regex to validate only specific urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm creating a reg exp for validating only those URLs from the list where parameter p has a value between 100 and 9999.
So from the list given below, only 3rd and 4th URL need to return true as output when they are entered into a textbox.

```
http://www.website.com/our-resources/news/?p=1
http://www.website.com/example/voice-of-the-customer/news/?p=12
http://www.website.com/our-resources/news/?p=123
http://www.website.com/example/?p=4321
http://www.website.com/example/products/touchchat/news/?p=12345
```

HTML

```
<input type=url/>
<button>Validate</button>
<div id=status></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var val = $('input').val();
    var regex = /^(https?:\/\/)?[a-z0-9-]*\.?[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9-]+(\/[^<>]*)?$/;
    var isValid = regex.test(val);
    $('#status').text(isValid);
});
```

But this regex returns true for all URLs.
What changes should I make to this expression?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/0rq4k6a8/)

Comment: Do you also have to check if all of them are valid URLs?

Comment: Yes, that too but only return true for those urls having value of p between the range i mentioned. I'm validating all urls using that expression but range check aint happening. @gurvinder372

Comment: To test regexes you write please checkout: https://regexr.com/
It's a fancy website to test if your regex is valid and matches everything as desired :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to [retrieve the querystring parameter from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) then check to see if its value meets your bounds:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var p = parseInt(getParameterByName('p', $('input').val()), 10) || 0;
  var isValid = p >= 100 && p <= 9999;
  $('#status').text(isValid);
});

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url)
    url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results)
    return null;
  if (!results[2])
    return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10pt Verdana;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="url" value="http://google.com/" />
<button>Validate</button>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)

```
var fnGetURL = ( strURL ) => {
   try
   {
      return new URL( strURL );
   }
   catch(e)
   {
      return null;
   }
};
```

And get [searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) if `null` is not returned

```
var fnIsValidURL = ( strURL ) => {
   var url = fnGetURL( strURL );
   if ( url )
   {
      var p = +url.searchParams.get("p");
      return p >= 100 && p <= 9999;
   }
   return false;
};
```

**Demo**

```js
var fnGetURL = (strURL) => {
  try {
    return new URL(strURL);
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
};


var fnIsValidURL = (strURL) => {
  var url = fnGetURL(strURL);
  if (url) {
    var p = +url.searchParams.get("p");
    return p >= 100 && p <= 9999;
  }
  return false;
};

var urlArr = ["http://www.website.com/our-resources/news/?p=1",
"http://www.website.com/example/voice-of-the-customer/news/?p=12",
"http://www.website.com/our-resources/news/?p=123",
"http://www.website.com/example/?p=4321",
"http://www.website.com/example/products/touchchat/news/?p=12345"];

urlArr.forEach( function(url){
   console.log( url, fnIsValidURL(url) ); 
});
```

Comment: An ideal solution in a perfect world, but be aware that `URL()` has no support at all in IE and `searchParams` is unsupported in Edge and Safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
function isValidParam(url) {
    if ($.urlParam('p',url) > 99 && $.urlParam('p',url)<10000) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Call above method to check URL validity

```
$.urlParam = function(name,url) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)')
            .exec(url);
    if (results == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return results[1] || 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: No need to call `urlParam` twice with the same arguments. Cache the result and make it simpler.

Comment: I know. I just hinted you how to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too simple but I found this regex working fine for what you're looking for.

```
/(?:http://[\S]*)\/\?p=(\d{3,4})$/g
```